# How to get sum of records based on another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
JobCode  | Designation | SalaryWithIncrement
----------------------------------------------
JC001 |    IT    | 150,000
JC001 |    IT    | 155,000
JC002 |    Sales | 100,000
JC003 |    HR    | 200,000
JC003 |    HR    | 210,000
JC003 |    HR    | 220,000
```

Required output:

```
JobCode |   Designation |   SalaryWithIncrement
------------------------------------------------
JC001   |   IT          |   305,000
JC002   |   Sales       |   100,000
JC003   |   HR          |   630,000
```

Below is the code I used, but I don't get grand total after grouping

```
SELECT JobCode, designation, salaryWithIncrement
FROM table1
group by (JobCode)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you get 150 + 155 = 205? I think you've made a typo.

Comment: Thanks. I can never be too sure if it's a typo or I've misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregate [`sum`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function:

```
SELECT   JobCode, designation, SUM(salaryWithIncrement)
FROM     table1
GROUP BY JobCode, designation
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases when you have such requirement, Implement using GroupBY with SQL Aggregate function
Group the Fields based on what you want records, in youu case `JobCode` and `designation`
You can learn about Group BY here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

```
SELECT JobCode,designation,SUM(salaryWithIncrement)
FROM  Job GROUP BY JobCode,designation
```

Here is your sample working code [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5307/1)

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to use the `sum` function in a `group by` statement.

```
select jobCode, designation, sum(salaryWithInc) from Job group by jobCode;
```

Check this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/231e4/3) to see a working example.

In my opinion, you have to restructure differently your table to avoid the data redundancy (`jobCode` and `designation`). For this you can have two tables, one with the `jobCode` and `designation` and the other with the `salaryWithInc`.

```
create table Job (jobId int auto_increment, jobCode varchar(5), designation varchar(25), primary key (jobId));
create table Salary (job int, salaryWithInc decimal(5,2), foreign key (job) references Job (jobId));
insert into Job (jobCode, designation) values ("JC001", "IT"),("JC002", "Sales"), ("JC003", "HR");
insert into Salary values (1,150.00), (1,155.00),(2,100.00),(3,200.00),(3,210.00),(3,220.00);
```

In this case, you use this query to get the required result:

```
select J.jobCode, J.designation, sum(S.salaryWithInc) from Job as J join Salary as S on J.jobId=S.job group by (J.jobId);
```

Check this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbb445/5) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!